# Php include 'file.php + link'

Tags: php

Is it possible to use "php include" that calls the first link existing in another .php file.

Here below how my files are structured. What I trying to do is to click PROJECT which will open the file project-one.html

I guess :first-child does not work in the HTML file...

in the HTML file I have:

```
<ul>
<li><?php include 'menu.php:first-child';?>PROJECT</li>
</ul>
```

in the PHP file I have:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="project-one.html">P1</a></li>
<li><a href="project-two.html">P2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: No, that makes no sense. PHP doesn't know anything about HTML structure.

Comment: The argument to `include` is a filename. That will look for a file whose name ends with `:first-child`

Comment: Right... is there anyway to do what I am trying to do? I am trying to link the first <li> in the PHP because it is always the "most up to date" article which I update every few days.

I was also trying to use this below, but I do not know how to write the string and if it is even possible.

<li><?php include 'menu.php/ul/first-child-something here/help';?></li>

Comment: you could do `<li><?= menu('li:first-child', 'PROJECT') ?></li>`, with alittle bit of effort could make a menu function which loads and parses xpath/domdocument the file menu.php, then passes second param as the link lable

Comment: Why are you doing this with static files instead of a database that you query?

Comment: I am not expert unfortunately. PHP is already out of my reach :)

Comment: You are messing concepts from PHP, HTML and CSS there. However, I guess I got what you are trying to achieve, check if my answer makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a file that centralises the link creation, you could do like so:

**index.php** <- *you need this file to be `PHP` (regular `HTML` files won't run `include` and php functions and code)*

```php
<?php
include 'linkgenerator.php';
?>

<ul>
<li><?php renderlink(1); ?></li>
</ul>
```

**linkgenerator.php**

```php
<?php
function renderlink($linknumber) {
    if ($linknumber == 1) {
        echo "<a href="project-one.html">P1</a>";
    } else if ($linknumber == 2) {
        echo "<a href="project-two.html">P2</a>";
    } 
}
```

A proper implementation would involve more advanced concepts, but if you are learning this is a good starting point to understand the principles.